# What does it mean for a non generic class to extend a generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

```
public class B extends C <A> {

}
```

What does this mean? That C needs to extend A? What extra restriction am I putting instead of just saying B extends C?

Answer (score 18):

In this case, `C` is a class that can take a generic parameter, and you are giving it a specific type `A` as the parameter. Then, `B` extends that specific parameterization of `C`.

For example, suppose:

```
class C<T> {
    T example();
}

class B extends C<Integer> {
}
```

Then `B.example()` would return an `Integer`.

Comment: The current example does not explain any benefit of having `class B` over using `C<Integer>` directly.  It only really makes sense if there is some `Integer`-specific behaviour in `B`.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining a class B that inherits from class C, parameterized with type A.  A must be a class or interface.

E.g.

```
class MyStringList extends ArrayList<String>
```

means that `MyString` IS AN `ArrayList` that will only contain `String` elements.  This class could then define e.g. a `concatenate()` method that returns the concatenation of all `Strings` in the list.

Because of this inheritance, you will be able to assign an instance to a `List<String>` variable:

```
List<String> strings = new MyStringList();
```

But you will not be able to assign it to `List` type variables with other parameters:

```
List<Object> objects = new MyStringList(); // does not compile
```

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface in case you want to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

`C<A>` does not mean that `C` is extending `A`, it means it can have `A` as the type parameter.

This is very similar to `Comparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>` interfaces in java.

Consider following example

```
public class NameSort implements Comparator<Employee> {
   public int compare(Employee one, Employee another){
       return (int)(one.getName() - another.getName());
   }
}
```

means that Comparator is using Employee objects for sorting them using its name.

You can also take another example

```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This line means that `List` is using `String` objects as parameters

Comment: Thanks. Can you pelase elaborate a bit what you mean by "have A as the type parameter"?

Comment: I have updated my answer @Victor, by type, I mean you can use that type in your generic class.

Answer (score 1):

Class `B` is a `C`.

`C` and `B` are parameterized with an `A`. (Which means they can have methods and such that use `A` methods, or the methods of classes that descend from A.)

A classic use case for this would be that you have a DAO (Data Access Object). You make a generic DAO with some basic methods, like `GenericDAO` with a generic `save` method. To make it so other DAOs can extend `GenericDAO`, you parameterize that class with `Entity`, and you make sure all your `Entity`s are saveable.

Then you have `GenericDAO<Entity`, and a bunch of implementations of that, for example `UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User>` where User is an entity.

Answer (score 0):

### In simple words

That doesn't mean anything, unless there are some **methods** defined in `Class C` or its **ascendants**, to either **accept** or **return Type A** parameters.

By doing so you are ensuring the  **Type safety** by imposing restrictions saying ***"They can accept or return objects of Type A".***

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B extends C <A> {

}
```

1. If A is undefined there is no restriction on B( can be any the of Object Class).
2. If the Type of A is defined,then B must be of type A or a Subclass of A.